# bluetooth listener works in debug mode, doesn't work in release mode/IPA react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, ipa

I have a bluetooth listener that works fine in debug mode of my iOS app.  However, when I build the IPA for it.  It no longer works.

Here's the listener

```
   setupBluetooth() {
        console.log('the setup')
        this.aDeviceStatusChanged = OVBluetoothEventEmitter.addListener('oliveDeviceStatusChanged', event => {
            console.log('the event', event)
            if (EventUtils.eventCodeEquals(event, 'DISCONNECTED')) {
                NavUtils.resetTo(this.navigator, 'ListPage', { originPoint: true });
                console.log('last chance')
            }
        });
    }
```

What could be causing the Listener to fail when I run the app via IPA?

Here's the updated code:

```
setupBluetooth() {
        console.log('the setup')
        this.somethingDeviceStatusChanged = SomethingBluetoothEventEmitter.addListener('somethingDeviceStatusChanged', event => {

            console.log('the event', event)
            console.log('the event', event.code)
            let tempStr = JSON.stringify(event.code);

            if (tempStr === '"DISCONNECTED"') {



                NavUtils.resetTo(this.navigator, 'somethingListPage', { originPoint: true });
                console.log('last chance')


            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that DEBUG mode runs considerably slower than Release/IPA versions of the app.  Also, due to Java/Objective-C being multi threaded, memory release occurs nearly instantly, whereas in Javascript(which is singlethreaded) there's a queue.  The result is when running in release mode, the memory release occurs so quickly on the Java/Objective C side that by the time the Javascript code runs, that event/variable no longer exists.  The work around for this problem was to create a variable to hold the Event, so that even upon memory release, the JS code has something to read.